# Dark screen after log in on Ubuntu 18.04, Dell Precision 7350

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I am posting this after very thorough search of similar issues.

**System config**

- Laptop make: Dell Precision 7530
- Hardware config: Nvidia Quadro 1000 4GB GDDR5, Intel Xeon 2.9Ghz, 32GB DDR4 RAM,
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Kernel: 5.3.0-40-generic

**Relevant drivers and software**

- Gnome 3.28.2
- nvidia driver v. 435
- gdm3 and lightdm installed, using gdm3

**Issue description**

After boot, the login screen *always* comes up. I log in, after which the screen turns black and slightly changes shade several times, and remains dark. There is no way out of this state, `ctrl` + `alt` + `F*` doesn't work and the only way is to turn off the computer.

I know that the OS in fact boots because if i) I blindly open the terminal and type `sudo shutdown` or `sudo reboot` it actually does; and ii) I plug in an external monitor the GUI works normally - i.e. it's just the built-in monitor.

When I log in using Wayland everything works, *but* some programs that I still need for work do not support it (Matlab).

**What I tried so far**

1. Change `gdm3` to `lightdm` using `dpkg-autoconfigure`. This doesn't solve the issue, behavior same.
2. Updating nvidia drivers. I purged the drivers and re-installed them using ubuntu-install, so they currently sit at v 435. No change.
3. I purged gdm3 and reinstalled.

I am happy to provide any log that might help with this. 
Does anybody have any idea what might be going on?
Thanks!